# Can PDB use Python3.5+ type annotations/hints for autocompleting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, pdb

I've been using PDB pretty extensively for a python3 project but I'm noticing autocomplete often doesn't work as well as I'd expect when debugging **inside of functions** when running PDB through **ipython**.

Most of the time when I type some variable followed by a period I expect pdb to have autocomplete suggestions for what methods I'm capable of calling. By default, it seems PDB doesn't use any type hints I've inserted as a way to suggest autocompletions.

I assume this is because type annotations are essentially erased at runtime so PDB doesn't have access to that information.

My question: **Is there any builtin way I can make PDB use python3 type annotations as a means to make autocomplete suggestions?**

For example, given some class:

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def get_property():
        ...
```

and some function:

```py
# test.py 

def debug_this(test: MyClass):
    # set breakpoint here
```

If I set a breakpoint inside of `debug_this` and try to tab complete `test` inside of PDB, I'd expect something like the following:

```
$ ipython -m pdb test.py
(Pdb)> break 4
(Pdb)> continue
(Pdb)> test. # then press tab
test.get_property(
```

But instead I get no matches found.

(I believe it's possible to write a custom complete function for my .pdbrc but I just want to know if there's any way to avoid that headache.)

Edit: I should note that the autocomplete functionality works for global variables that aren't declared in the scope of a function because pdb is certain of the type of those variables. I just want to see if I can force PDB to assume my type annotation is correct and suggest the corresponding autocompletions using that assumption.